# GPS ACCURACY IN ALL SCENARIOS ANDROID

Tags: android, gps, location

I am working on a project which is GPS related. I have used both GPS and Network Provider to fetch the coordinates of current location.But the problem I am facing is Sometimes,It couldn't fetch the accurate location.
Also,when I am inside the building or closed roof my application couldn't fetch the accurate GPS location.
So,if anyone could help me by suggesting the best way of dealing with the location manager and the providers,it would be very helpful for me.

Please find the code below:

```
public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

GPS is only accurate with a good clear view of the sky, as the signals are of a wavelength that don't penetrate buildings easily. This means that if you're between tall buildings, you may get an inaccurate position (canyon effect), and if you're inside, you may not get a GPS fix at all. Even if you are outside, with a good view of the sky, the accuracy of a GPS fix is much less than the resolution.

This is not something that can be overcome with code, as it is down to physical limits.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Even we thought the same that we can not overcome this problem with any changes in the code.

Comment: It should read "with a free view to the sky". The term "clear" is a bit misleading, One can think clouds would disturb, which is not the case.